# Translation symmetry and the non-conserved momentum in Viscous fluids

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, lagrangian-formalism

Even though a viscous fluid has a translation symmetry (invariance) for its Lagrangian , it still 'waste'  Linear momentum. How come ?, isn't the rule that every symmetry yields a conservation law ?

Comment: Could you write down that Lagrangian? The rule exists indeed...

Comment: I don't know  the Lagrangian for it,to be frank. But since the force is : $m$.a=-c.$v$.I noticed that the momentum would be      p=$e$-^((c/m) $t$) and this is a declining function with time.   And since the speed would not vary with position, in other words, the it's translation invariant , then there is symmetry for translation. How can I reconcile this two contradicting ideas ?! .

Comment: It seems that you are now referring to the Lagrangian of a particle in a fluid and not of the fluid itself. That Lagangian is $L=e^{-ct/m}m \dot{x}^2/2$. This Lagrangian is, in fact, translationally invariant. However, since it is not of the form $T-U$, the constant of motion associated with that symmetry is not the momentum. Applying Noether's theorem one easily sees that it is $e^{-ct/m}m \dot{x}$.

Comment: It's true that I was referring about a particle in a viscous fluid,but I didn't make that clear.So ,What makes this example come out with such a result ,i.e that the translation  symmetry is associated with other than the momentum?.My hunch is that these equations come from a statistical frame of work.thnx